# failed to access to a value in a json variable

Tags: node.js, syntax

I have some troubles with a variable after doing some mongodb processing

```
...................
console.log("MIP : value :" + value._id );
console.log("MIP : page id :" + value._id.id ); 
....................
```

The logs show this

```
MIP : value :{ id: '346593403645', _id: 57a868497e07fcf75f27009c, __v: 0 }
MIP : **page id :undefined**
```

I am not understanding why the value of *value._id.id* is undefined

Could you help please

Comment: it would be better if You put in Your question the result of: console.log('Value is:', value);  nobody cannot predict what kind of data You're handling.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like You keep serialized data in `value._id`.

So try:

```
if(typeof value._id == 'string') {
  value._id = JSON.parse(value._id);
}
```

also keep in mind that when You want to dump the variable don't concatenate variable with string.

just do:

```
console.log("MIP : value :", value);
```

it will show You the variable as is:
 - if it's buffer so will show that it's buffer
 - if object so will output it as object

Seems like Your json is malformed.
So use dirty-json package:

```
var dJSON = require('dirty-json');

dJSON
    .parse(value._id)
    .then(function (result) {
       console.log(result.id);
    });
```

Comment: it seems that the problem is with _id key in the object

Comment: Error means that JSON.parse cannot read json data because it's not proper serialized json. "Unexpected token i" means that Your json string is malformed and keys must be double quoted

Comment: Please do console.log(value) and post somewhere

Comment: I've added to my answer an example with dirty-json package that understands format and returns result inside promise. p.s. npm i --save dirty-json